# Operate with app_data .mdf database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using Visual Studio 2013. Created Web Forms Project. Added some stuff and needed database. 
Also, added database using Add Item. 
Added some stuff to a database. 
Use connection string from Web Config. 
When connection is made, i got some errors.

Here is my connection string >

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

C# code >

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505.mdf");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users;");
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(cmd, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
```

here is the errors

Error   1

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.DataSet.DataSet(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)' has some invalid
>   arguments c:\users***\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Project\Default.aspx.cs  30  26  mywebsite

Error   2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo'  c:\users***\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Default.aspx.cs  30  38  Administration Website

Error   3

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'
>   to
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext'   c:\users***\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Default.aspx.cs  30  43  mywebsite

When error is clicked it's focus on DataSet.

Help ?? Some better idea to connect to my database ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You have made some errors in initializing your DataSet and your SqlDataAdapter, the correct way is

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users;");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

It is the `SqlDataAdapter` instance that needs the `SqlCommand` as parameter for one of its constructors, as you can easily spot [on MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx). Then the connection is bound the the `SqlCommand.Connection` property and you should enclose the creation of the `SqlConnection` in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to be sure that it is closed and disposed at the end of the using block

You can also remove two lines from the code above passing the connection directly to the constructor of the SqlCommand (again [MSDN pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) are a treasure of information) and remove the opening of the connection because, if the Adapter finds the connection closed, it opens and closes it automatically

About a different topic, you have correctly stored your connection string in the config file of your application. This allows you to easily change it (if the need arises) But you have used an hard coded connection string. This should be changed to something like this

```
 string connString2 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\***\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\App_Data\aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505.mdf' as database 'aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505'.**

What's the problem with the connection string ?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I rewrite the code.   `string connString2 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;‌​`  <br/> `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString2))`   <br/> `{ <br/> SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("shortsql");`  <br/>  `cmd.Connection = con;`  <br/>`con.Open();`  <br/>  `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`  <br/>  `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`  <br/> `da.Fill(ds);` `con.Close();  <br/> } `

It gives error (please see next comment)